# 3D Vector linear interpolation

Tags: java, 3d, trigonometry, lerp

How can I lerp between two 3d vectors?
I use this method for 2d vectors:

```
public Vector2d lerp(Vector2d other, double speed, double error) {
    if (equals(other) || getDistanceSquared(other) <= error * error)
        return other;
    double dx = other.getX() - this.x, dy = other.getY() - this.y;
    double direction = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    double x = this.x + (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    double y = this.y + (speed * Math.sin(direction));
    return new Vector2d(x, y);
}
```

Note: this is not exactly "linear interpolation"; this method will interpolate at a constant rate, which is what I want.

I want to do exactly what this does but with an added z component for the third dimension. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to transform your two vectors such that they lie in the `(u, v)` plane; then apply your method above; then transform back to the original coordinate space.

This requires you to construct a rotation matrix:

1. Take the cross product of your two vectors to get the mutual normal vector; call this `cross_1`;
2. Define that `this` points along the `u` axis;
3. Take the cross product of `this` and `cross_1` to get a vector `cross_2`, which is the direction of your `v` axis.
4. Normalize each of these three vectors; call them `this_norm`, `cross_2_norm` and `cross_1_norm`.

These three vectors can be written as a 3x3 orthonormal matrix (each of the vectors is a 3-element column vector):

```
R = [ this_norm cross_2_norm cross_1_norm ]
```

Now: you can multiply your 3d vectors `this` and `other` by this matrix, and you will get vectors which have the form

```
[  u  ]
[  v  ]
[  0  ]
```

i.e. a 3-dimensional column vector with zero as the third element (or, at least, you should. I may have forgotten to transpose the 3x3 matrix above).

So, you can obviously discard the third element, and have 2-element column vectors:  you can store these in `Vector2d`. And so you can apply your method above to do the interpolation.

That gives you a `Vector2d` which interpolates in the `(u, v)` plane. You can transform that back to the `(x, y, z)` space by attaching a zero third element to it, and pre-multiplying by `R'` (which is the inverse of `R`, since it is orthonormal).

---

Of course, you need to handle degenerate cases, like zero and (anti-)parallel vectors. In these cases, one or both of the cross products are zero, meaning you can't normalize them; simply pick arbitrary directions instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, when you compute dx and dy offsets, then compute angle from it, and finally sin/cos pair - you're basically normalizing the dx,dy vector, so you could write it like that:

```
Vector2d delta = other - this;         // I'm not sure about your API here,
delta.normalize();                     // you may need to fix those lines
double x = this.x + (speed * delta.x);
double y = this.y + (speed * delta.y);
```

Now it should be straightforward to add a Z component.